# json file 404 with ?option

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to make a notice board that can be filtered down to what year is was intended for. I intend on adding the data to a json and filtering it using ?userId=. If I remove the .json and attempt to use ?userId=1 or similar then I get a 404 error. If I leave the .json and add ?userId= var then opens the json but shows all the entries. Below is my code:

```
function getPosts(option){

  fetch('linktojson/file.json' + option)
  .then(status)
  .then(json)
  .then(function(dataList) {
    getData = dataList;
    var divReply = $(".reply")
    divReply.empty();

    dataList.forEach(function(data){
      var post = $('<p class="post"/>');  
      var divTitle = $('<div class="title"/>').append(data.title);
      var divBody = $('<div class="body"/>').append(data.body)

      divReply.append(post.append(divTitle,divBody));

    });

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Fetch Post Error :-S', error);
  });
}
```

If I manually browse to my .json and add the ?userId I also get a 404 error. The json code is below:

```
[
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "whole school 1",
      "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "year 7",
      "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Test year 8",
      "body": "1234"
    }
 ]
```

I am out of my depth with this being honest. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `?somequery` parameter only works with endpoints, not physical files. If you have a server endpoint `\some-endpoint\` that serves the json data instead of a json file, then you can use url query strings and capture the parameters.

Comment: an alternative would be to capture the url parameters before doing the fetch, then do the fetch without the parameters and use the parameters after you get the data. But this seems kind of roundabout.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it easy to set a endpoint up? I've never had to before.

Comment: Forgot to say, I'm using IIS

Comment: What backend are you using? C#? Node?

Comment: Hi, I'm not too sure tbh. Is there a way to tell in IIS?

Comment: I will use ASP.Net, so C#.

Comment: Here's a good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

The web api will return a json response at the endpoint you specify in the controller's attribute routing parameter. You could download the sample project and run it in visual studio to see how it works.

Comment: You're a star. Thank you.